# Authenticate both Controllers and WebAPI after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I've an MVC 4 C# application that uses WebAPI to acquire data. I use the standard Visual Studio MVC template to start the project with Identity authorization.

Now I've to secure ajax calls to WebAPI and I need to store Identity OAuth token for example in sessionStorage or something like it.

My question is: How to acquire the token from controllers and store it browser side?

Following SPA template from VS I wrote something like this:

```
var fragment = common.getFragment();

if (fragment.access_token) {
     window.location.hash = fragment.state || '';
     sessionStorage.setItem("access-token", fragment.access_token);
} else {
     window.location = "/Admin/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
}
```

this way I force browser to reload the page acquiring token from URL via Javascript and then remove it from URL. But this refresh brings few problems with `redirectUrl` pattern and other stuff.

Is this the only way or best practice?